# Set Foreign Key in PHPMy admin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to set foreign key using PHPMy admin. But the problem is the attribute which I am going to use as foreign key is existed in two tables. 
Think I have tables A,B,C
A and B has a  'P' attribute which is primary key in A and B. 
I want to set that  'P' attribute as foreign key in C table.

Answer (score -1):

Think about merging A and B into one table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, No, It s not possible.  I am in the database implementing state. when merge the table, atomicity of the database is lost.

Comment: So the only way is to create separate db columns in C, like P_A and P_B and set foregin keys for these columns. Both columns should be nullable so you could not set one of them.